# Trying to correct a function

Tags: python-3.x, function

i'm very new to coding in python (or anything).  i have to create a function that will return the speed of a vehicle based on how far it skidded when braking.  i'm getting a 'float' object not callable error when i try and run my doctests.  i've tried changing the name of the variables a couple of ways and can't seem to get it right.  probably missing something simple.

```
import math

def car_speed(distance_of_skid):
    '''
Calculate the speed in MPH of a car that skidded
d feet on dry concrete when the brakes were applied

args:
    distance_of_skid (float): the distance of the skid in feet

returns:
    an estimate of the speed the car was going when the brakes were applied (float)

formula:
    speed in MPH equals the square root of (24 * d)

examples/doctest:

the car didn't skid at all
>>> round(car_speed(0), 2)
0.0

the car skid 1 foot
>>> round(car_speed(1), 2)
4.9

the car skid 10 feet
>>> round(car_speed(10), 2)
15.49

the car skid 33.33 feet
>>> round(car_speed(33.33), 2)
28.28

the car skid 12345 feet
>>> round(car_speed(12345), 2)
544.32

'''
    d = distance_of_skid
    car_speed = math.sqrt (24 * d)

    return (round(car_speed(d), 2))
```

feel like i'm making it more complicated than it is (professor has mentioned this previously).  the output of the function should be the speed in MPH rounded to 2 decimal places.

Comment: What are you expecting car_speed(d) to return?

Comment: it needs to return the vehicle speed in mph rounded to 2 places

Comment: Aah, I skimmed over the beginning of the file. My bad. DX

So it seems like you're trying to call the function from within the function? In the final line of the function.

Comment: yep, that was the error.  as soon as i changed that constant name and reran, it worked.  knew it was something simple.  thanks!!

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it! Would you mind creating an answer that explains what you changed, including showing the modified code, for the benefit of future readers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to saffronsnail, i was able to figure it out.  i used the function name as a constant and that caused the issue.  changing the constant name to something different fixed it.  changed car_speed to just speed in the return line.

```
> '''
>     to run tests on mac: python3 -m doctest car_speed.py -v
>     to run tests on Win: python -m doctest car_speed.py -v ''' import math
> 
> def car_speed(distance_of_skid):
>     '''
>     Calculate the speed in MPH of a car that skidded
>     d feet on dry concrete when the brakes were applied
> 
>     args:
>         distance_of_skid (float): the distance of the skid in feet
> 
>     returns:
>         an estimate of the speed the car was going when the brakes were applied (float)
> 
>     formula:
>         speed in MPH equals the square root of (24 * d)
> 
>     examples/doctest:
> 
>     the car didn't skid at all
>     >>> round(car_speed(0), 2)
>     0.0
> 
>     the car skid 1 foot
>     >>> round(car_speed(1), 2)
>     4.9
> 
>     the car skid 10 feet
>     >>> round(car_speed(10), 2)
>     15.49
> 
>     the car skid 33.33 feet
>     >>> round(car_speed(33.33), 2)
>     28.28
> 
>     the car skid 12345 feet
>     >>> round(car_speed(12345), 2)
>     544.32
> 
>     '''
>     # TO DO: Add your code here
>     d = distance_of_skid
>     speed = math.sqrt (24 * d)
> 
>     return (round(speed, 2))
```